# 1ex in tabular breaks tex4ht ODT conversion

Tags: tables, spacing, tex4ht, conversion

I included the `[1ex]` spacing command in a `tabular` and attempted to convert to ODT using `tex4ht` (`make4ht -f odt file`). It doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    one & two & three \\[1ex]
    1 & 2 & 3
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{document}
```

The Java interpreter (I think) gives this error message, and everything goes haywire from there:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 8; 
The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
        at xtpipes.Xtpipes.execute(Xtpipes.java:1300)
        at xtpipes.Xtpipes.execute(Xtpipes.java:783)
handler="xtpipes.util.ScriptsManagerLH" > : While parsing file file:/tmp/tex/convert.tmp: : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
59; columnNumber: 8; The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
--- Warning --- System return: 256
```

Loading the `booktabs` package and using `\addlinespace` *does* convert successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the configuration for the vertical space in table inserts the `&nbsp` entity for non breaking space. This entity is not declared in the ODT xml, which results in the `Xtpipes` error. I will fix this issue in `tex4ht`, in the meantime you can use the following configuration file, `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HBorder}
   {<table:table-row  \Hnewline table:style-name="hline-row">%
}
      {<table:table-cell table:style-name="hline-cell"
                         table:value-type="string">%
          <text:p text:style-name="hline-p-hr"  />%
       </table:table-cell>\Hnewline
}
   {</table:table-row>\Hnewline
}
   {<table:table-row\Hnewline table:style-name="cline-row">\Hnewline
}
      {<table:table-cell table:style-name="cline-cell">%
          <text:p text:style-name="cline-p"  />%
       </table:table-cell>\Hnewline
}
      {<table:table-cell table:style-name="cline-cell">%
          <text:p text:style-name="cline-p-hr"  />%
       </table:table-cell>\Hnewline
}
   {</table:table-row>\Hnewline
}
   {<tr\Hnewline class="vspace-si-delas" style="font-size-grr:\HBorderspace">%
}
       {<td\Hnewline>\string&\csname :sharp\endcsname xA0;</td>%
}
   {</tr>%
}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This configuration inserts the `&#xA0;` entity, which should be OK. Compile using:

```
make4ht -f odt -c myconfig.cfg file
```

The result in LO:

[image]